# Using Data.Array in a Haskell Data Type

Tags: haskell

I have been developing some code that uses Data.Array to use multidimensional arrays,
now I want to put those arrays into a data type so I have something like this

```
data MyType = MyType { a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: Array }
```

Data.Array has type:

```
(Ix i, Num i, Num e) => Array i e
```

Where "e" can be of any type not just Num.

I am convinced I am missing a concept completely.

How do I accomplish this?
What is special about the Data.Array type that is different from Int, Num, String etc?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where are you getting that context for `Array`? `Num i, Num e` don't look right to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Array` is not a type. It's a *type constructor*. It has *kind* `* -> * -> *` which means that you give it two types to get a type back. You can sort of think of it like a function. Types like `Int` are of kind `*`. (`Num` is a type class, which is an entirely different thing).

You're declaring `c` to be a field of a record, i.e., `c` is a *value*. Values have to have a type of kind `*`. (There are actually a few more kinds for unboxed values but don't worry about that for now).

So you need to provide two type arguments to make a type for `c`. You can choose two concrete types, or you can add type arguments to `MyType` to allow the choice to be made elsewhere.

```
data MyType1 = MyType { a, b :: Int, c :: Array Foo Bar }
data MyType2 i e = MyType { a, b :: Int, c :: Array i e }
```

---

References

- [Kinds for C++ users](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Kinds).
- [Kind (type theory) on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_%28type_theory%29).

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the type variables `i` and `e` to your `MyType`:

```
data MyTYpe i e = MyType { a, b :: Int, c :: Array i e }
```